# out of memory error(given solution did not work)

Tags: java, jvm, bpel, bea

I am running following script for starting my bea weblogic workshow 8.1.4, workshop start properly and function very well

> C:\bea\weblogic81\workshop 
>       C:\bea\jdk142_05\bin\javaw.exe
>       -XX:-UseThreadPriorities -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Xss256k -client -Dbpelexport.java.home="C:\bea10.3\jdk160_05\"
>   -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Djava.system.class.loader="workshop.core.AppClassLoader"
>   -cp "C:\bea\weblogic81\workshop\wlw-ide.jar"
>   workshop.core.Workshop

```
But when i start exporting my process(means these lines come in picture -Dbpelexport.java.home="C:\bea10.3\jdk160_05\") I am getting following error

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
    at javelin.SourceBuffer.read(SourceBuffer.java:123)
    at javelin.SourceBuffer.getReader(SourceBuffer.java:63)
    at javelin.SourceFile.getBufferedReader(SourceFile.java:378)
    at javelin.SourceFile.getReader(SourceFile.java:405)
    at javelin.SourceNode.getReader(SourceNode.java:221)
    at javelin.java.JavaCompiler$Parser.parse(JavaCompiler.java:77)
    at javelin.work.WorkParse._parseNode(WorkParse.java:224)
    at javelin.work.WorkParse.parse(WorkParse.java:156)
    at javelin.work.WorkParse.run(WorkParse.java:91)
    at javelin.threading.WorkList.runItem(WorkList.java:500)
    at javelin.threading.WorkItem.ensureComplete(WorkItem.java:103)
    at javelin.work.WorkCompile.run(WorkCompile.java:69)
    at javelin.threading.WorkList.runItem(WorkList.java:500)
    at javelin.threading.WorkList$WorkerThread.run(WorkList.java:292)
```

My system has 3 GB of RAM.

is there any way i can supply memory parameters to jdk1.6 java.exe also in the same script.

suggest me something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the `-Xmx` argument to give the process more memory, such as `-Xmx=2G` to allow Java use 2 gigs of memory. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but the thing is like when weblogic starts jdk1.4 comes in picture where we have already supplied paramter but when jdk1.6 comes in picture(invoking event) then it went down(outofmemory) my question is how we will supply memory paramter to dk1.6 in script(-Dbpelexport.java.home="C:\bea10.3\jdk160_05\")

Comment: it'd be `-Xmx2g` not `-Xmx=2G` for 2GB.